# SQL Variable not getting set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I might be missing something easy here, as someone relatively new to SQL, I am trying the following query:

```
DECLARE @uidd VARCHAR
SELECT @uidd = UID
FROM PRODUCTOBJECT WHERE EMAIL='abc@gmail.com';
SELECT ProductID FROM PRODUCTUIDMAPPING WHERE UID= @uidd;
```

And it is returning zero rows.  What's puzzling is that if do not use variables and run both selects separately, I do get the right row back.

```
SELECT UID FROM TABLEA WHERE EMAIL='abc@gmail.com';
```

returns the UID, and then

```
SELECT ProductID FROM TABLEB WHERE UID='123456';
```

will return the ProductID value, where '123456' would be the value returned from the first query.

The problem is when combined together, using the variable for some reason it seems @uidd is not being set.  Any reason why ?

I am running this on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, `uuid` is longer than one character.  *Never* use character types in SQL Server without a length.  The default varies by context and may not be correct.

So, this should work:

```
DECLARE @uidd VARCHAR(255);

SELECT @uidd = UID
FROM PRODUCTOBJECT
WHERE EMAIL='abc@gmail.com';

SELECT ProductID
FROM PRODUCTUIDMAPPING
WHERE UID= @uidd;
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the super fast reply and you were right.  Within the next 12 minutes I can accept the answer :)